# Best way to compile a dynamic ADODB SQL Statement based on user input

Tags: javascript, sql, mysqli, adodb

I need your help,

How can I program a user defined dynamic SQL query.

I have 4 text fields on my webpage.

```
var a = document.getElementById('prefix').value
var b = document.getElementById('firstname').value
var c = document.getElementById('middlename').value
var d = document.getElementById('lastname').value
```

How can I use javascript to compile and build an SQL statement if the user fills out either one of the textboxes.

For example, prefix, lastname and firstname are filled in:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PREFIX = a AND LASTNAME = d AND FIRSTNAME = b
```

For example, firstname and lastname are filled in

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FIRSTNAME = b AND LASTNAME = d
```

Is there a better process, other than to use a bunch of if statements to check any 4 of the given conditions?

Seems like iterating through a whole wack of if statements is redundant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you're asking, but an alternative to using 4 if statements would be to include them in your SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (PREFIX = a OR a = '') 
    AND (LASTNAME = d OR d = '')  
    AND (MIDDLENAME = c OR c = '') 
    AND (FIRSTNAME = b OR b = '')
```

This way, if the values are blank, it won't search for them.

Comment: No value given for one or more parameters:

Comment: SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_rssims "
   + "WHERE "
   + "(FIRSTNAME = "+ firstname +" OR "+ firstname +" = '') "
   + "AND (LASTNAME = "+ lastname +" OR "+ lastname +" = '')"

Comment: @JohnSmith -- seems to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7862/3 -- my only guess with your above comment is you need to put single quotes around your fields (i.e. LASTNAME = '" + lastname + "'... Be careful though, that approach is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Best regards.